# Integrating Apple Pay with a Springboot-ReactJS Application and Authorize.net as Payment Processor

Tags: reactjs, spring-boot, payment, authorize.net, applepay

I have generated a CSR file from Authorize.net. I then gave this CSR file and then generated both Payment Processing Certificate and Merchant Identification Certificate. But when I saw the Authorize's doc, I can't find how and where to use these certs. Doc: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#mobile-in-app-transactions-create-an-apple-pay-transaction

Went through the Apple Pay JS API doc and saw there is a need to verify the merchant. For that I used keytool to generate a .p12 file from the merchant_identifier.cer given by Apple. But how to use this in a backend perspective?